# Groups with 3 conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory

How to find (describe) all groups which have 3 conjugacy classes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $|Z(G)| \leq 3$. So there is not any p-Group with $p \not= 3$. I'll try to obtain more.

Comment: It's good to post the work you've done up until now, whenever you post a question.

Comment: I would guess that this is very difficult (probably impossible) for infinite groups. There are many infinite groups with just two conjugacy classes. Perhaps the exercise was just about finite groups?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52350/finite-groups-with-exactly-n-conjugacy-classes-n-2-3?rq=1

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664300/for-general-n-in-bbb-n-how-to-determine-all-groups-both-finite-and-infini

Answer (score 1):

Well, the unit element is always a conjugacy class by itself, just as any element is in any abelian group,  so you need other two classes...for example, the (cyclic) abelian group of order $\,3\,$, but also the permutation group $\,S_3\,$, which only has transpositions and $\,3-$cycles.

It could be now a nice exercise to show the above are the only *finite* groups, up to isomorphism, with three conjugacy classes.

About infinite groups I don't know: constructions like HNN show there can be very funny groups all the non-unit elements of which are conjugated, so this may require lots of care

Comment: Are you sure that there is not any other?

Comment: In fact I remembered once having done this, yet I wasn't completely sure. The following paper though supports this: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02764723

Comment: I'm trying to understand why. I just discovered that if we call $C_1, C_2, C_3$ the conjugacy classes than $|G|= \frac{|C_2||C_3|}{|C_2||C_3|-(|C_2|+|C_3|)}$, calling $C_1$ the class of $e$. This seems to be possible just for 3 and 6 (Wolfram computing).

Comment: I'd rather write the above as $$|G|=1+\frac{|G|}{|C_2|}+\frac{|G|}{|C_3|}\Longleftrightarrow 1=\frac{1}{|G|}+\frac{1}{|C_2|}+\frac{1}{|C_3|}$$ Observe that we can assume $\,|G|>3\,$ and non abelian, so it can't be that $\,|C_2|\geq 4\,$ and etc. Try to finish this.