# number of groups with fixed number of conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory

why is there only finite number of (finite or infinite)groups with a fixed number of conjugacy classes?
I know this is classical ,so plz give me a reference if you have.
thank you

Comment: group is not necessarily finite in my case

Comment: I am not sure that there are finitely many isomorphism types with a given finite number of conjugacy classes if you allow infinite groups. I think there are infinite groups of prime exponent $p$ with $p$ conjugacy classes, for example, and I think there are infinite groups with two conjugacy classes.

Comment: are u sure?
can u give me a reference plz?

Comment: You can embed any torsion free group in a group with only two conjugacy classes. This is a standard application of HNN extensions.

Answer (score 2):

In 1903 Edmund Landau proved that, for any positive integer $k$, there are only finitely many finite groups, up to isomorphism, with exactly $k$ conjugacy classes. I think the paper is to be found in the Math. Annalen 56, in German (*Über die Klassenzahl der binären quadratischen Formen von negativer Discriminante*). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52350/finite-groups-with-exactly-n-conjugacy-classes-n-2-3).

Comment: i cant read german but it seems it is in finite case at the end.
has it proven for all groups in this?

Comment: Yes, for finite groups. See the link in my answer: for infinite groups the situation is different.