# Characters of irreducible representations of odd-order groups

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I want to prove that if $G$ is a group and the order of $G$ is odd, and $\chi$ is a real-valued irreducible character of $G$, then $\chi$ must be the trivial representation, $\chi = \epsilon$.

So far, I know that $|G| = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} n_i\chi_i^2$, and that $|G|$ odd $\implies \exists j \in \mathbb{N}: |G| = 2j+1$. Therefore:

$2j+1 = n_1 \chi^2 + \sum_{i=2}^n n_i \chi_i^2$, and therefore $n_1\chi^2$ must be even and $\sum_{i=2}^n n_i \chi_i^2$ even, or both of them must be odd. Since I have no further information about the characters of the other irreducible representations of this group, I am not sure how to proceed. Any tips?

Comment: What are the $n_i$ here? Are you looking at real or complex representations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\chi \in Irr(G)$, with $\chi \neq 1_G$ (the trivial character). Apply the orthogonality relation to $\chi$ and $1_G$, then
$$\sum_{x \in G}\chi(x)=0.$$
Now assume that $\chi$ is real-valued. Then $\chi(x)=\overline{\chi(x)}$ (complex conjugate) for all $x \in G$. From the orthogonality formula above one has
$$\chi(1)=-\sum_{x \in G-\{1\}}\chi(x).$$
But $\chi(1) \mid |G|$, so the degree of $\chi$ is odd. The oddness of $|G|$ also implies that for all $x \in G-\{1\}$, $x\neq x^{-1}$, so
$$\sum_{x \in G-\{1\}}\chi(x)=\sum \chi(x)+\chi(x^{-1}),$$
where the last sum is taken over a set of *disjoint pairs* $\{x,x^{-1}\}$. Now $\chi(x)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of a matrix representing $x$, while $\chi(x^{-1})$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of the inverse of that same matrix. The eigenvalues of the matrix are roots of unity and for a root of unity $\zeta$, one has $\zeta^{-1}=\overline{\zeta}$. Since $\chi$ is real-valued one must have $\chi(x)=\chi(x^{-1})$. It follows that
$$\frac{1}{2}\chi(1)=-\sum_{x}\chi(x).$$
We now have a contradiction: the left hand is half an odd positive integer, while the right hand side is an algebraic integer.

**Note** (added April $20^{th} 2019$) The above appears also as Problem (3.16)  (a result of William Burnside) in Isaacs' book *Character Theory of Finite Groups*. It has the following very nice consequence, which is Problem (3.17) of the same book.

**Theorem** Let $|G|$ be odd and suppose the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ is $k$. Then $|G| \equiv k$ mod $16$.

**Proof** By the previous the non-principal irreducible characters come in $\frac{k-1}{2}$ pairs, $\chi$ and $\overline{\chi}$ and for all characters $\chi(1)=\overline{\chi(1)}$. Now we know that $$|G|=\sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)}\chi(1)^2= 1+\sum_{\chi \neq 1_G}\chi(1)^2=1+2\sum_{i=1}^{ \frac{k-1}{2}}\chi_i(1)^2$$
Since $\chi_i(1)$ divides $|G|$ it must be odd, and odd squares are $\equiv 1$ mod $8$. So for each $i$, we have $\chi_i(1)^2=1+8a_i$, with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $|G|=1+2\sum_{i=1}^{ \frac{k-1}{2}}(1+8a_i)=k+\sum_{i=1}^{ \frac{k-1}{2}}16a_i$ and the result follows.

There are various generalizations of the result, some of them coming from Björn Poonen, American Mathematical Monthly **102** $(1995)$, no. $5$, pp. $440-442$ and Michael Reid, American Mathematical Monthly **105** $(1998)$, no. $4$, pp. $359-361$. See also the paper by Robert van der Waall, Elem. Math. **25** $(1970)$, $136–137$.

Comment: Thank you Nicky. I actually ended up following a similar procedure, but I just computed the scalar product $(\chi, \epsilon)$  and showed it is different from 0.

Answer (score 4):

Another standard proof consists in working with the character table $T$, as a matrix whose $(\chi, g)$ entry is $\chi(g)$, where $\chi$ ranges in the irreducible characters of $G$, and $g$ ranges in a set of representatives of the conjugacy classes.

Consider the permutation of the rows that takes row $\chi$ to row $\overline{\chi}$. So this takes $T$ to $A T$, where $A$ is a suitable permutation matrix.

Consider the permutation of the columns that takes the column $g$ to the column of (the class of) $g^{-1}$. Once more, this takes $T$ to $T B$, for a suitable permutation matrix $B$.

Since $\overline{\chi(g)} = \chi(g^{-1})$, we have $A T = T B$. Since $T$ is invertible, $A$ and $B$ are conjugate, so in particular their traces, that is, the numbers of fixed points of the corresponding permutations, coincide.

Now if an element $g \in G$ is conjugate to its inverse, $g^{x} = g^{-1}$, for some $x \in G$, then $g^{x^{2}} = g$, so $x^{2} \in C_{G}(g)$, which yields $x \in C_{G}(g)$, as the order of $G$ is odd, so that $g = g^{-1}$, and $g = 1$, once more because the order of $G$ is odd.

Therefore the trace of $B$ is $1$. But then the trace of $A$ is also $1$, that is, there is only one character $\chi$ such that $\chi = \overline{\chi}$, and then it has to be the trivial character.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the [Frobenius–Schur indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator), you can argue as follows:

Suppose not, i.e., $\chi$ is not the principal character, then by the orthogonality relationship, we have $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)=0$.

Note that the Frobenius-Schur indicator can be computed as:
\begin{align}
\nu_2(\chi)&=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g^2).
\end{align}
But $|G|\equiv 1\pmod 2$ implies $g\mapsto g^2$ is a bijection of $G$. Hence
$$\nu_2(\chi)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g^2)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)=0.$$

The Frobenius-Schur indicator equals $0$ can only happen when $\chi\ne\overline\chi$ which is a contradiction.