# Let $G$ be a group of odd order, $k$ be a number of conjugacy classes in $G$. Show that $G\equiv k\pmod{16}$. What is meant by $G\equiv k\pmod{16}$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, representation-theory

I am struggling with this exercise:

Let $G$ be a group of odd order, let $k$ be a number of conjugacy classes in $G$. Show that $G \equiv k\pmod{16}$.
What is meant by $G \equiv k \pmod{16}$? Isn't it supposed be cardinality of the group or something like that? Not just $G$?

To be honest, I am completely lost with that.

Comment: Use `\pmod{16}` to get the modular parenthetical symbol, and use `\equiv` for the equivalence symbol.

Comment: It means that $16$ divides $|G|-k$.

Comment: If you are struggling with the question itself, not just with the wording, there is a thread about exactly that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38694/surprising-but-simple-group-theory-result-on-conjugacy-classes

Comment: @lulu: Are you saying that "$G\equiv k\pmod{16}$" is a typo and should be "$|G|\equiv k \pmod{16}$", or that it is meaningful notation as written?

Comment: @Troposphere   i don't know if it is a typo because I don't have the original text.  But the classical result in this context is that $16\,|\,(|G|-k)$ so I assume that is what  the OP meant.

Comment: @lulu It was like I wrote in the original text, so probably a typo. It is from my university lectures, so not any official material.

Comment: Ok.  So, they meant to write $|G|$ when they wrote $G$.  Or whatever notation they use for the order of the group.

Comment: So now the meaning of the question has been explained to you, you need to provide some context.  You have asked three questions in rapid succession with very little context.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: hi all, what is special about mod 16 here? why not just mod 8 or mod 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is a typo.

What it should read is this:

$$\lvert G\rvert\equiv k\pmod{16},$$

which means $16\mid \lvert G\rvert-k$. Here $\lvert G\rvert$ is the *order* of $G$.

---

As for the question itself, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38694/104041).

Comment: can you explain what is special about mod 16 here? (why not just mod 8 or mod 4?)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38694/104041), @МаринаMarinaS.